# Integration sonar with jacoco. I see excluded packages in sonar coverage report

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, jacoco-maven-plugin

I want to migrate from cobertura to jacoco codecoverage tool.
I'm using maven as build tool and I added jococo-maven-plugin in my pom.xml file. its configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2.201409121644</version>
    <configuration>
        <append>true</append>
        <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
        <outputDirectory>${jacoco.output.path}</outputDirectory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>com/acmecorp/acmeproject/mbean/**/*.class</exclude>
            <exclude>com/acmecorp/acmeproject/model/**/*.class</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-site</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So after performing `mvn clean install` jacoco generates me some pretty html pages with code coverage. And this document looks exactly how I want it to look.

The second step I need to perform is integrate jococo with sonar. Previously I integrated sonar with cobertura. So I simply removed cobertura specific properties and added properties related to jococo.

```
<properties>
    <!--<sonar.cobertura.reportPath>target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>-->
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.projectKey>${project.artifactId}</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.projectName>ACME Project</sonar.projectName>
    <sonar.projectVersion>${project.version}</sonar.projectVersion>
    <sonar.java.source>${java.compliance.level}</sonar.java.source>
    <sonar.sources>src/main/java</sonar.sources>
    <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://4.4.8.8:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;rewriteBatchedStatements=true&amp;useConfigs=maxPerformance</sonar.jdbc.url>
    <sonar.jdbc.driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
    <sonar.jdbc.username>ranos</sonar.jdbc.username>
    <sonar.jdbc.password>ranos</sonar.jdbc.password>
    <sonar.host.url>http://4.4.8.8:9000/sonar/</sonar.host.url>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/sites/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <jacoco.output.path>target/sites/jacoco/</jacoco.output.path>
</properties>
```

Maven plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</plugin>
```

and profile

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

As a result I get such code coverage on server:

[image: As a result I get such code coverage on server]

[image]

And I see that in generated coverage report on server I see that my excluded packages are included in report. When I use cobertura everything worked fine.

So may be someone could help me with this. I do not want to add exclusions for sonar configuration. I really hope that it could be some additional configuration for jococo plugin.

**UPDATE**

In case I use cobertura maven-plugin with sonar
(I mean if I comment this line `<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/sites/jacoco/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>` and uncomment this one `<sonar.cobertura.reportPath>target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.cobertura.reportPath>`)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exclusions need to happen not on the JaCoCo side, but on the SonarQube side, and be specified via the SonarQube UI, rather than in your POM.

The docs will give you details: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreCodeCoverage

Comment: Hi Ann, but if I change only one line in sonar-maven plugin(uncomment cobertura coverage report ) then sonar report looks perfect. Check update section of my question

Answer (score 0):

Put packages that you want to exclude in maven `<properties>` block in your `pom.xml`:

```html
<properties>
  <sonar.jacoco.excludes>*model*,*generated*,*exception*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
</properties>
```

If that does not work, try changing property name to `sonar.coverage.exclusions`, I think it changed in later versions.